# Получить значения массив input

Tags: javascript, html

view

```
<form id="formx">
 <tr id="massage">
   <td style="width: 10%"><?php echo "Цена дроп"?></td>
   <td style="text-align: right; width: 10%">
   <?php foreach($price_cost as $result){ ?>
   <?php echo $result['code'];?>:<input type="text" name="cost_price_drop[]" class="cost_price_drop[]" size="8" value="<?php echo $result['price_cost']; ?>"><br>
   <?php } ?>
   </td>
   <td style="width:5%"><input type="text" id="price_ukraine" value=""></td>
   <td><input type="button" id="button_drop"></td>
  </tr>
 </form>
```

scrypt

```
 $('#button_drop').on('click', function () {
    var ms = $(".cost_price_drop").val();
    console.log(ms);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/massage&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
        data:{
            "massage":ms
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#massage').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Но приходит только одно значения, как сделать что бы приходило со всех полей?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button_drop').on('click', function () {
    var ms = $("#formx").serialize();
    console.log(ms);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/massage&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
        data:{
            "massage":ms
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#massage').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

P.S. "massage" - кровь из глаз просто)

Comment: Как обработать в php ?

Comment: Получаю Array ( [massage] => cost_price_drop%5B%5D=0.00&cost_price_drop%5B%5D=0.00 )

Comment: в index.php в переменной $_POST:

echo $_POST;

Comment: Все верно, у вас же:

name="cost_price_drop[]"  value="<?php echo $result['price_cost']

name="cost_price_drop[]" - это ключ в массиве POST, он же в urlencoded cost_price_drop%5B%5D

и
value="<?php echo $result['price_cost'] - то что хранится по ключу, он же 0.00.

Comment: сделал так name="cost_price_drop" echo $_POST приходит ответ  cost_price_drop=0.00&cost_price_drop=0.00 а мне то надо по  отдельности что бы было

Comment: Сделайте в цикле счетчик:
<?php $i =0;
foreach($price_cost as $result){ ?>
   <?php i++
echo $result['code'];?>:<input type="text" name="cost_price_drop[<?php echo i ?>]" class="cost_price_drop[]" size="8" value="<?